# Creating a class vs using a dict for "smaller" objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have the following:

```
class Product

    def __init__(self, name="Pepsi"):
        self.name = name
        self.daily_sales = []
```

And the `daily_sales` object is something like this:

```
{
    "date": 2019-01-01,
    "price": 1.99,
    "revenue: 283.01
}
```

And the `daily_sales` in the `Product` class will just have a bunch of those sales_objects. My questions is, when should something like a dictionary be converted into a separated class? When does it make sense to, and when does it not make sense to? For example:

```
ProductDailySale:
    def __init__(self, product_id):
        self.product_id;
        self.date;
        self.price;
        self.revenue;
```

Comment: `dict` objects are *maps*. If you want a map then use a `dict`. If you want a separate data type use a custom class instance. Alternatively, if you want a lightweight containers that acts like a simple "struct" you can use a `collections.namedtuple`, although, you can always just use a custom class with slots if you are worried about memory overhead. I am of the opinion that you should never use `dict` objects the way you are using them (although, given the ubiquity of the JSON serialization format, it happens often)

Comment: Are you going to do operations on the data? Or just storing it? If just storing it, I'll go with NamedTuples instead of a class. If you have operations that are done on the data (related to the data) I'll go with a class.

Comment: If you are going to query / manipulate / extend daily_sales it would make sense to me to create a separate class.

Comment: Look into dataclasses if you have methods as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guidance would be to almost never use dicts as data structures with fixed layout.

Instead, use classes.  A convenient way to define simple data classes is  [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) or, in older versions of Python, [`attrs`](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs).

I've found two major advantages to this over using dicts, especially when used with pytype and static code analysis:

1. It is possible to annotate fields with type signatures (and get static type checking).
2. Misspelled field names are caught at build time instead of causing failures (sometimes silent — think `dict.get()` returning `None`) at run time.

Comment: I totally agree, unfortunately, a lot of Javascript people use it this way because they conflate python `dict` objects with Javascript Objects, but a dataclass is really just a convenience, it's just a normal class really.

Comment: @NPE -- could you please show an example with the above code on how you'd use the `dataclasses`? I had never heard of those before.

Comment: @David542 he's saying just use a class. The `dataclass` decorator is just a nice, convenient way to create these sorts of "classes that just hold data" with minimal boilerplate, but you should really try to grok the core of this answer is saying, which is "don't use dict objects for this at all"

Comment: @NPE -- also in looking that over, it seems like it's just a class at its core?

Comment: @David542 yes, it is exactly equivalent to a class you would write yourself it just serves as a convenience.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Thanks — that was the gist of my argument, though it clearly wasn't expressed very well.  Edited.